# Basic prolog program. I can't find my error

Tags: prolog

when i type write(jk,hp). ,it doesn't work , it says "ERROR: write/2: stream `jk' does not exist". i know that am a beginner so what is wrong with it?

```
write(jk,hp).
write(martin,got).
write(james,orangeland).

write(A,B):-
   write(A),write('has written'),write B, nl.
```

The relationship between author and book is as follows: writes(A,B) means author, A, has written book ,B.

Declare a few facts with well-known authors and the books they released, and write a program which lists all the books written by a particular author.

Note: After you get the first result, press ';'.
Or,
Try the following : ?- writes(,B), write(B), nl ,fail.

Comment: this code seams to be prolog, why did you tag it C++ ?

Comment: IIRC, `write/2` is a standard predicate which writes to a stream. Using conflicting names can cause surprises.

Comment: This code sample is quite a mess. Does it even compile? (It definitely does not compile for me!)

Comment: @shrike oops yeah , i made a mistake tagging other things in that...im quite new here sorry.  so what should i do to resolve it? i created a new file and named it , what could be the conflict?

Comment: quite a mess? what do you mean? its just a few lines codes. well it doesn't compile, do you know why?

Comment: `s/write B/write(B)/`.  But better do not use I/O predicates as a beginner!

Comment: Did you read the error messages? What do they say? They must give you line numbers, at the very least. By "mess" I mean that it's messy and probably not valid Prolog source.

Comment: "Quite a mess" because: (1) `write B` isn't valid. This is Prolog, not Ruby. ;) (2) You should not write your own predicate with the same name as a Prolog standard predicate. And to avoid other issues, I recommend that you should name your facts differently than your predicate.

Comment: thx you very much everyone who helped me, you are all great!

Comment: i posted the question from which im trying... can anyone help me solve it?

Comment: @IanTwy:  You seem to be going in circles, without stopping to read the Comments with understanding.  Your "facts" should not used the predicate `write/2` because that is a system-defined predicate.  Instead pick a predicate name like `authored_book` or whatever is meaningful and not duplicative of a standard Prolog system-defined predicate.

Comment: @hardmath: yes i understood that. i changed the name to 'writes' and ran it in swi prolog online and it worked. no errors. but when i ran it on sublime text 3 , it didn't work at all. when i type 'writes' , and ask a question, it tells me 'correct to : write(x,y)?' and when i say no, it says error....